# Should Generated i18n.dart file be migrated to Null Safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm migrating a project to Null Safety which has a `generated` `i18n.dart` file

- Should I migrate it to Null Safety too with the migration tool or should I leave it out ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify generated code. You should re-run the intl tool to generate null-safe code during you migration.

To re-generate the generated code, installe the [intl_util](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_utils) package by adding it to your pubspec.yaml file and running `flutter pub get`.

Then run `flutter pub run intl_utils:generate` to generate the code again.

Comment: how do I generate it ?

Comment: @Sunshine See the updated answer.